# Is possible to reset the timer on a disabled iPhone without Wi-Fi or Cellular?

Tags: iphone, wifi, cellular-data, unlock, ntp

After the screen was replaced on my iPhone 4S, I a got "disabled for 24+ millions minutes" text on my screen due to battery being unplugged. Unfortunately I have disabled cellular data and I wasn't connected to any Wi-Fi network. Is possible to unlock my iPhone without erasing data? I know the device's passcode.

Comment: Can you swipe up from the bottom to control center, turn airplane mode on, then off again. What happens? I think that time is transmitted over cellular network, even when data is off.

Comment: Thanks for comment. No, I unfortunately can't. Only think I can do is to call emergency.

Answer (score 2):

Connect the device to the same iTunes library which the device synchronises with over USB. This will reset the disabled timer and allow you to enter your passcode.

Comment: Unfortunately i haven't got any computer synced with this device (not anymore). So it means that I lost my data? Although i know my passcode, Apple Id etc. ?

Comment: Problem was, that half of screen stopped working and I could not unlock it. I was abroad, so I have disabled Wi-Fi and Cellular data. There is no way how to change settings of iPhone to enable Wi-Fi or Cellular data over USB? Thanks a lot!